# Does std::construct_at make an array member of a union active?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Look at this example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fh888f5ab)):

```
#include <memory>

union U {
    int i[1];
};

constexpr int foo() {
    U u;
    std::construct_at(u.i, 1);
    return u.i[0];
}

constexpr int f = foo();
```

gcc and msvc successfully compile this, but clang complains:

> construction of subobject of member 'i' of union with no active member is not allowed in a constant expression

Which compiler is right? I think that clang is wrong here, because C++20's implicit creation of objects ([P0593](http://wg21.link/p0593)) should make this program valid (because the array should be implicitly created, which should make `u.i` active), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure, but adding a `{0}` initializer to the member declaration (i.e. `int i[1]{0};`) resolves the issue. Also, is that link to P0593 part of the C++20 Standard, or a *proposal* to add it to the (next) Standard?

Comment: It was voted into the working draft of C++20 as defect report in Prague http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4855.pdf and is listed on Cpp Reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20 as supported since Clang 11

Comment: @AdrianMole: I think P0593 is part of C++20: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#general-9 (n4868 is the closest draft to C++20 afaik). I'd like to avoid the initializer, because the whole point of using an union is to defer initialization.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, if you're deferring initialization, aren't you implicitly deferring activation? Again, I don't know, but it seems logical (sort of). (You can only add such an initializer to one part of a union, BTW.)

Comment: So, if you had another union member - say `float j[1];` - then which is implicitly activated?

Comment: @AdrianMole: I'm deferring activation, that's right (that's not a goal, though. My goal is to defer initialization of the array elements). But creating a subobject should implicitly create the array, which should activate `u.i`. At least, this is my theory. But I'm not sure, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: @AdrianMole: `i`, because I call `std::construct_at` on a subobject of `i`. If I called `std::construct_at` on a subobject of `j`, then `j` should be activated.

Comment: But isn't that the point? A `constexpr` expression is not allowed to activate a member.

Comment: @AdrianMole: it's allowed in C++20

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake regarding placement-new using `operator new` in my answer. Now I am wondering whether implicit object creation works in constant expressions at all. [\[intro.object\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-10) says that objects are created if necessary to give the program defined behavior, but would the program being ill-formed not count as defined behavior?

Comment: @user17732522: I'm not sure that you were wrong. Maybe there is no implicit creation involved at all here, because this case is not present in the list you cited. The storage is not acquired by operator new, malloc, etc., but it's an inactive union member.

Comment: @geza A placement-new is still calling `operator new`, even if that specific overload is specified to just return its argument. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-13 does not seem to say that `operator new` has to actually be allocating the storage, just returning it.

Comment: @user17732522: There are two things here: 1. what operation is used to make implicit lifetime object creation possible. This is the list you've cited. 2. What operation is executed which touches the object. I use `std::construct_at`, but I could have used a simple assignment as well. This doesn't matter. To make implicit creation happen, 1. matters. And I don't use a technique from 1., so implicit creation won't happen. But, tbh, if this example doesn't work, then I don't see what could make an array member active. A simple assignment to an array member should create the whole array...

Comment: "Similarly, the evaluation of a call to std​::​construct_­at [...] does not disqualify E from being a core constant expression unless the first argument, of type T*, does not point to storage allocated with std​::​allocator<T> or to an object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of E [...]."

Comment: @user17732522: ... so it makes sense to me that calling `std::construct_at` on an array member should also create the whole array

Comment: @Sebastian That seems like a clear answer.

Comment: @geza The array object could be implicitly created after the `std::construct_at` call.

Comment: @user17732522: no, implicit creation has to happen before this call. I mean, `std::construct_at` should be called on a result of `new`, `malloc`, or on a `char[]`, etc. But this is not the case here, so no implicit creation happens. At least, this is how I understand.

Comment: "because the whole point of using an union is to defer initialization" -> why not replace union with struct and still use std::construct_at later?

Comment: @Sebastian: If a struct used, then `i`'s ctor will be called (if it has one - the example I presented is a simple one. In my real code, `i` can be anything). I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: @geza: "*I'd like to avoid the initializer, because the whole point of using an union is to defer initialization.*" Then you're using them wrong. Deferring initialization isn't the point of a `union`. If you want to defer initialization, then use an `optional`; that way, you can keep track of when initialization has happened.

Comment: The best solution to not call the constructor early would be to store a pointer, allocate uninitialized memory with the allocate() function of std::allocator<MyObject>, use std::construct_at() when needed and call deallocate() at the end. This works with all 3 compilers as constexpr, and before/without construct_at the object is unitialized. If optional also works, even better.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I use union to defer initialization **in this example**, that's the point of using it. `optional` cannot be a solution for my problem (because I need a contiguous array of objects, and I also construct array elements one by one. `optional` cannot do these.). And `optional` is usually implemented with unions, for the very same reason I use union here.

Answer (score 11):

```
U u;
```

does not begin the lifetime of the `i` subobject. Beginning the lifetime of a variable other than an array of type `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte` is also not one of the operations specifically qualified to be *implicitly creating objects*. [[basic.intro.object]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-13)

Therefore at this point the `i` member is definitively not active and the array object is not alive.

As mentioned by @Sebastian in the question comments, calling `std::construct_at` on `u.i` is then not allowed in a constant expression since [[expr.const]/6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#6.1) specifically requires the provided pointer to point to an object whose lifetime began during the evaluation of the constant expression (or be storage returned from `std::allocator`).

Therefore Clang seems correct to me. There is an open GCC bug for exactly this issue [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102286).

I am not sure that this is the intended interpretation though, since Clang does accept the program if a non-array type is used for the member, which by my reasoning would equally not be allowed.

The relevant wording is a consequence of [this](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/43) comment.

In any case, it is not intended that implicit object creation happens in constant expressions although it currently seems to ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556755/does-implicit-object-creation-apply-in-constant-expressions)), see [CWG issue 2469](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2469).

Without implicit object creation as explained below, the use in a context requiring a constant expression should then be ill-formed independently of the `std::construct_at` restriction and the following considerations.

---

Whether the construction has defined behavior if used outside a constant expression context, I am not entirely sure.

But I think that `std::construct_at` being specified to be equivalent to a *new-expression* means that it will call `operator new`, which is specified to implicitly create objects in the storage it returns. [[basic.intro.object]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-13)

Whether `operator new` must be an allocating `operator new` call for this to be true is not fully clear to me. I think the wording "in the returned region of storage" does not require it.

`i` is of type `int[1]`, which is an *implicit-lifetime type*, which are implicitly created if necessary by operations qualified to implicitly create objects. [[basic.types.general]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#types.general-9)

Therefore I think that `construct_at` will implicitly create the an array object at `u.i` and begin its lifetime. I also think that [[basic.intro.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-2) will guarantee that this object becomes subobject of the union, so that `u.i` will refer to it.

However, given that the storage operated on is only the size of a single `int` and assuming that this is also the storage meant in [[basic.intro.object]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic#intro.object-13), only an array of length `1` can be implicitly created in it. Therefore if `i` was of length larger than `1`, the implicitly created array could not overlap exactly with the member and can therefore not become subobject of the union.

In this case implicit object creation could not make `return u.i[0];` defined behavior.

---

There is a discussion of this issue [here](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2021/09/3171.php) which seems to indicate that already forming the pointer to the first element of `u.i` outside its lifetime is UB, in which case the `construct_at` version with array would more directly have UB, but at least compilers accept both `auto x = u.i;` and `auto x = &u.i[0];` in a constant expression without complaining. As mentioned in the comments to this answer, this also seems wrong.

---

All in all I think that `std::construct_at` can generally *not* be used to activate an array member of a `union`.

---

But, suppose you replace the `std::construct_at` call with

```
u.i[0] = 1;
```

Then this assignment will begin the lifetime of the array object, as described in [[class.union.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.union#general-6). This is not disqualified for constant expressions since C++20 either. Therefore the code will not be ill-formed if used in a context requiring a constant expression, nor will it have undefined behavior outside of that.

Comment: _There is a discussion of this issue here which seems to indicate that already forming the pointer to the first element of u.i outside its lifetime is UB_ You mean [this](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2021/09/3174.php) message? It is wrong. It is OK to apply the array-to-pointer conversion to an expression denoting an array outside its lifetime, it is OK to do arithmetic on a pointer denoting an element of such an array and it is OK to apply the unary indirection operator `*` to such an expression, it will just produce an lvalue denoting an object outside lifetime.

Comment: _Therefore I think that `construct_at` will implicitly create the array object i and begin its lifetime. I also think that [basic.intro.object]/2 will guarantee that this object becomes subobject of the union, so that u.i will refer to it._ It may be important to note that this is true only for the array of length 1 and not true for larger arrays.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer You mean because the returned storage of `operator new` would be limited to the size of a single `int`?

Comment: Not that it is explicitly specified, but I think this is the intent. That `operator new` implicitly creates objects only in the storage its arguments denote.

Answer (score 0):

Deferred initialization of an array in a `constexpr` environment can be achieved with `std::allocator` and `std::construct_at()`:

```
#include <memory>

constexpr int foo() {
    std::allocator<int> alloc;
    int* i; // pointer to first element of array

    i = alloc.allocate(100); // allocate memory for 100 elements

    std::construct_at(&i[0], 1); // initialize first element (first call of constructor)

    int r = i[0];
    alloc.deallocate(i, 100); // deallocate before leaving
    return r;
}

constexpr int f = foo();
```

---

Pointers to the relevant standard clauses:

`allocate`:

[[utilities.memory.default.allocator.members]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/allocator.members): `std::allocator<>::allocate()` obtains storage by calling operator `::new` and starts the lifetime of the array object, but not the lifetime of the array elements themselves.

[[expr.const]/5.19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.19): Explicitly allows `std::allocator<>::allocate()` in constant expressions, if the memory is deallocated again within the constant expression

`construct_at`:

[[algorithms.specialized.construct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/specialized.construct): std::construct_at() effectively calls placement new.

[[expr.const]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#6): Explicitly allows `std::construct_at` in constant expressions, if the memory is allocated by `std::allocator`

`deallocate`:

[[expr.const]/5.19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.19): Explicitly allows `std::allocator<>::deallocate()` in constant expressions, if the memory was allocated before within the constant expression

Comment: Please note that this is a [language-lawyer] question, so you need to address whether the code shown in the question is valid, or not. An answer showing alternative code that has some related effect, is not really an answer to the question at all.