# Does implicit object creation apply in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
    constexpr auto v = [] {
        std::allocator<char> a;
        auto x = a.allocate(10);
        x[2] = 1;
        auto r = x[2];
        a.deallocate(x, 10);
        return r;
    }();
    return v;
}
```

Is the program ill-formed? Clang thinks so, GCC and MSVC don't: https://godbolt.org/z/o3bcbxKWz

---

Removing the `constexpr` I think the program is not ill-formed and has well-defined behavior:

By [[allocator.members]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/allocator.members#5) the call `a.allocate(10)` starts the lifetime of the `char[10]` array it allocates storage for.

According to [[intro.object]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#13) starting the lifetime of an array of type `char` *implicitly creates objects* in its storage.

Scalar types such as `char` are *implicit lifetime types*. ([[basic.types.general]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types.general#9)

[[intro.object]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#10) then says that objects of type `char` are created in the storage of the `char[10]` array (and their lifetime started) if that can give the program defined behavior.

Without beginning the lifetime of the `char` object at `x[2]`, the program without `constexpr` would have undefined behavior due to the write to `x[2]` outside its lifetime, but the `char` object can be implicitly created due to the arguments above, making the program behavior well-defined to exit with status `1`.

---

With `constexpr`, I am wondering if the program is ill-formed or not. Does implicit object creation apply in constant expressions?

According to [[intro.object]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#10) objects are implicitly created to give the program *defined behavior*, but does being ill-formed count as defined behavior?

If not, then the program should not be ill-formed because of implicit creation of the `char` object for `x[2]`.

If yes, then the next question would be if it is unspecified whether the program is ill-formed or not, because [[intro.object]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#10) also says that it is unspecified which objects are implicitly created if multiple sets can give the program defined behavior.

---

From a language design perspective I would expect that implicit object creation is not supposed to happen in constant expressions, because verifying the (non-)existence of a set of objects making the constant expression valid is probably infeasible for a compiler in general.

Comment: With it being unspecified which objects are created, I wonder if we can solve halt or collatz?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: All that isn't necessary. It's the expressions that use the objects which decide which ones are created. And without `reinterpret_cast`, your options for what objects could be created in that storage are limited.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean, my idea is that if you can make it ambiguous which object is created in a constant expression, and UB means a hard error in a constant expression, and the language demands that the code is not UB if *any* type created leads to non-UB, it looks close to having the ability to specify a NDTM or even an Oracle.  The idea would be to ambiguously create objects and make code whose definedness depends on a relationship between the types of the object.  This may be impossible, hence my "wonder".  Is it limited enough?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Even if `reinterpret_cast` could be used in constant expressions, it still wouldn't be hard to make IOC work. You don't need to create every possible type; you only need to create the type(s) needed to make a particular piece of code work. If someone dereferences the memory with an `int`, then you put an `int` there. If someone else comes along and dereferences it with some struct `S`, then you first check to see if the first subobject of `S` is `int` (ie: matches what is already there). If so, then you build the `S` around the existing `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ##### [2469. Implicit object creation vs constant expressions](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2469)
>
> It is not intended that implicit object creation, as described in 6.7.2 [intro.object] paragraph 10, should occur during constant expression evaluation, but there is currently no wording prohibiting it.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked the issues before asking. I was also thinking about how to abuse this with unions and `std::launder` but didn't come up with the examples given in the referenced issues.

Answer (score 2):

Clang is incorrect here. You've already cited all the parts in the spec that make it well-formed. `std::allocator<T>::allocate` is `constexpr`; you get a pointer to `char*`; `allocator<T>::allocate` creates an array of `T`; creating an array of `char` implicitly creates objects; accessing a `char` attempts to cause UB, but IOC prevents UB, so UB doesn't happen. Therefore: the code isn't allowed to be il-formed.

Clang claims full support for both IOC and constexpr allocators, so this code should work.

> Does implicit object creation apply in constant expressions?

All expressions are core constant expressions [unless [expr.const]/5 explicitly excludes it](http://Does%20implicit%20object%20creation%20apply%20in%20constant%20expressions?). Nothing there mentions operations which might be UB that determines which objects are created, so such operations must be included.

IOC *prevents* an expression from being UB.

> I would expect that implicit object creation is not supposed to happen in constant expressions, because verifying the (non-)existence of a set of objects making the constant expression valid is probably infeasible for a compiler in general.

You have forgotten about the other restrictions on constexpr code. So long as [expr.const]/5 continues to explicitly forbid `reinterpret_cast` and conversions from `void*`, the number of ways you can abuse IOC is pretty limited. You cannot, for example, take the pointer returned by your `allocate(10)` call and convert it to an `int*`. So the compiler knows that the *only objects* that can be implicitly created in that storage are `char`s.

So at constant evaluation time, the compiler could just take the result of `allocator<char>::allocate` and create all the `char` members of that array immediately before returning it. There's no constexpr-valid way for you to take that storage and implicitly create anything *other* than `char`s.

And using `allocator<T>::allocate` when `T` isn't a byte-wise type will not implicitly create objects in that storage. So either you're just getting a pointer to an array of unformed elements, or you're getting a pointer to an array of byte-wise types.

I'd guess Clang forgot to check this particular case.